# Generate random float numbers in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, floating-point, factory-bot

I need to generate random latitude and longitude values in my factories for testing, but using `Random` class gives me duplicate values and make my tests fail, how can I generate random float values in `FactoryGirl`?

**EDIT**: the relevant piece of code

```
factory :location do
  lat rand(-90.0..90.0)
  lng rand(-180.0..180.0)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) gem.

```
factory :address do
  latitude { Faker::Address.latitude }
  longitude { Faker::Address.longitude }
end
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Also has some pretty good features for other fields.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why you get duplicate values, but this would probably work:

```
lat = rand(-90.0..90.0)
lng = rand(-180.0..180.0)
```

You can [seed](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-srand) the number generator with a fixed value to get consistent random numbers in your tests.

In factory_girl:

```
factory :location do
  lat { rand(-90.0..90.0) }
  lng { rand(-180.0..180.0) }
end
```

Comment: In FactoryGirl doing that I get Attribute already defined: rand

Comment: @8vius could you add the relevant code to your question, please?

Comment: @8vius I've updated my answer, you have to use [lazy attributes](http://rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Lazy_Attributes)